# Кастомизация переключателей slick slider

Tags: css, slick.js

Как кастомизировать переключатели slick слайдера? Перебрал все стили, по умолчанию идут две круглые кнопки со стрелочкой внутри. Как мне это стрелочку сделать белой, а не прозрачной?

P.S. Прилагаю скриншот. Мне нужно сделать белые стрелочки на черном фоне (сейчас они прозрачные в сером кружке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В js настройках указываете код:

```
prevArrow: $('.arrow__left'),
nextArrow: $('.arrow__right'),
```

Теперь переключателями назначены блоки с классами arrow__left и arrow_right, которые можете кастомизировать как угодно

Comment: $('.slider-wrap').slick({
        prevArrow: $('.arrow__left'),
  nextArrow: $('.arrow__right')
      });
Вот так?

Comment: Всё верно, при инициализации слайдера через его параметры задаете нужные элементы.

Comment: а если на странице 3 слайдера, как задать стили точек в кадлом слайдере отдельно?